# Apache Camel with Play Framework

Tags: playframework, apache-camel

Do Play Framework supports Apache Camel?

If yes, can you please provide some reference documents?

Comment: I don't use the Play framework, but my understanding is that it's supposed to seamlessly integrate with Akka - so you might want to check out [akka-camel](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/camel.html) (especially if you already use some Akka actors in your Play application, obviously).

Comment: We can use Akka Actors in our application. So can I proceed with Play for Camel?